# Can C++20 using enum apply to templates?

Tags: c++, templates, enums, c++20, using-declaration

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support), both gcc and msvc have completed the implementation of C++20 feature [`using enum`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1099r5.html), which means we [can](https://godbolt.org/z/1bWxWjqe9) *using-declaration* with an `enum`:

```
struct A { 
  enum e { /* ... */ }; 
};

struct S { 
  using enum A::e;
};
```

But when I apply it to the templates:

```
template <class T>
struct S { 
  using enum T::e;
};
```

gcc [rejects](https://godbolt.org/z/KofW9fjbx) it with:

```
<source>:7:14: error: 'using enum' of dependent type 'typename T::e'
    7 |   using enum T::e;
      |              ^~~~
<source>:7:17: note: declared here
    7 |   using enum T::e;
      |                 ^
```

msvc also rejects it with:

```
<source>(7): error C2868: 'e': ill-formed using-declaration; expected a qualified-name
<source>(8): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'S<T>' being compiled
```

I have no idea why this cannot work since it seems to be no different from non-templates.

**Is this a compiler bug or just ill-formed?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1099r5.html#wording-changes):

> The elaborated-enum-specifier shall not name a dependent type and the type shall have a reachable enum-specifier.

In your example `T::e` is a dependent type.

Comment: Any idea as to why this is not allowed for dependent types?

Comment: @Timo no, not really ;)